# Web page load before showing

Tags: loading

Normally a webpage load images is like scrolling down. I don't want the visitor's of my site to see it. I am looking for a script that will load my webpage and then it will show completely. I have already put a **fadeIn** effect but the images loading is scrolling and also my background image.

**Questions:**

Is there a script for that?

What is the best script to use? PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: If you could do it with PHP, then you could do it with pure HTML, because when a page is scripted with PHP, all the client sees is HTML.

Answer (score 1):

this is one method, http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/panel-loading.html

basically you can wrap the content in a hidden div, then unhide it in the body's `onload` event.

Answer (score 1):

You could overlay your page with a "please wait..." `div`, and fade that out when the page is loaded. You could use JQuery's `ready` event to hide the div.

The downside of this is that users with JavaScript turned off would never see the page, but only the "please wait.." message.

To make it work for users with JavaScript turned as well, you would have to make the "please wait..." `div` visible using Javascript at a very early stage of the document's loading, which is very tricky to achieve. It might work if you put a `<script>` tag after the "please wait" div but before the actual page's content.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';">

<div id="loading">Some loading text or icon goes here...</div>

<div id="content" style="display:none;">Main content goes here...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can add on page header small copy's of this images.. 1x1 px and fade it or hide or z-index -100/   browser will download this full-size images